# tmux: Switch windows and panes with a single key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

## My Problem

`tmux` key bindings require two separate key hits to enter a command. The first is called a prefix, and set to <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>. The second key performs the actual command, [for example](https://gist.github.com/MohamedAlaa/2961058#windows-tabs):

- <kbd>c</kbd>  create window
- <kbd>w</kbd>  list windows
- <kbd>n</kbd>  next window
- <kbd>w</kbd>  previous window
- <kbd>f</kbd>  find window
- <kbd>,</kbd>  name window
- <kbd>&</kbd>  kill window

The problem is that two consecutive key combinations are cumbersome and slow. Most other tabbed UIs - from Chrome to Vim - enable tab switching with a single combination.

## What Have I Tried

- STFW
- Played with `bind-key` and `send-keys`, for example `bind-key C-c  send-keys C-a n`

## My Question

How can I run specific tmux commands, like "next window" or "create window", with a single key combination?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution

I have something like this in my `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
bind -n C-h select-pane -L
```

Maps `<Ctrl>-h` to select pane on the left.

## Manual [reference](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#KEY_BINDINGS_2) for the `-n` argument

```
bind-key [-nr] [-T key-table] key command [arguments]
    (alias: bind)
Bind key key to command.  Keys are bound in a key table.  By default (without -T), the key is
bound in the prefix key table.  This table is used for keys pressed after the prefix key (for
example, by default `c' is bound to new-window in the prefix table, so `C-b c' creates a new
window).  The root table is used for keys pressed without the prefix key: binding `c' to
new-window in the root table (not recommended) means a plain `c' will create a new window.
-n is an alias for -T root.  Keys may also be bound in custom key tables and the
switch-client -T command used to switch to them from a key binding.  The -r flag indicates
this key may repeat, see the repeat-time option.

To view the default bindings and possible commands, see the list-keys command.
```

Comment: For some strange reason, it does not work for me. Has anyone verified this in Linux/Terminator/Zsh?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for selecting windows. Use bindings that feel right to you. The accepted answer runs into the problem, using `C-h`, where you might pair it with `C-l`, but `ctrl+l` is often used in shells to clear the screen.

```
bind-key -n C-S-Left previous-window
bind-key -n C-S-Right next-window
```

See also `select-window` in `man tmux` for alternative ways to change windows.